# One class-based view object for multiple urls depending on parameters

Tags: python, django

I have multiple urls whose mission is almost identical (generate a list page with the corresponding context). So my `urlpatterns` is something like:

```
url('^by-country/(?<arg1>\w+)', MyO.as_view(), name='by-country'),
url('^by-period/(?<arg1>\w+)', MyO.as_view(), name='by-period'),
url('^by-age/(?<arg1>\w+)', MyO.as_view(), name='by-age')
```

Is there a way to pass the `by-blabla` string in a one class based view without making it as a second regex named argument in my `urlpatterns`?

Since I use a `View` derived class (i.e. `MyO`), I cannot pass anything to it except already-declared attributes (e.g `template_name`). So, is there any clean way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All url patterns accept a third positional argument, which is a dict of extra parameters to pass to the view that are not derived from the regex itself. So:

```
url('^by-country/(?<arg1>\w+)', MyO.as_view(), {'category': 'by-country'}, name='by-country'),
```

Comment: Are the extra arguments passed to the `dispatch` method of a class based view?

Comment: Thanks Daniel!, but where do I extract the `category` parameter? In my `get` method?

Comment: Thanks, it can be obtained from `kwargs`!